# List of files changed between commits with JGit

Tags: java, jgit, git-diff

I'd like to get the paths of the files changed (added, modified, or deleted) between two commits.

From the command line, I'd simply write

```
git diff --name-only abc123..def456
```

What is the equivalent way to do this with JGit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `DiffFormatter` to get a list of `DiffEntry`s. Each entry has a changeType that specifies whether a file was added, removed or changed. An `Entry`s' `getOldPath()` and `getNewPath()` methods return the path name. The [JavaDoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffEntry.html) lists what each method retuns for a given change type.

```
ObjectReader reader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
ObjectId oldTree = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD~1^{tree}" );
oldTreeIter.reset( reader, oldTree );
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
ObjectId newTree = git.getRepository().resolve( "HEAD^{tree}" );
newTreeIter.reset( reader, newTree );

DiffFormatter diffFormatter = new DiffFormatter( DisabledOutputStream.INSTANCE );
diffFormatter.setRepository( git.getRepository() );
List<DiffEntry> entries = diffFormatter.scan( oldTreeIter, newTreeIter );

for( DiffEntry entry : entries ) {
  System.out.println( entry.getChangeType() );
}
```

The above example lists the changed files between `HEAD` and its predecessor, but can be changed to compare arbitrary commits like `abc^{tree}`.

Comment: Just a question - why oldTree is under "newer" revision? Whis it old if it is new in fact.? HEAD^{tree} means current head commit(tree) while HEAD~1^{tree} is parent commit of current head - so its 1 commit behind.

Comment: You are right, `oldTree` and `newTree` should be changed. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Uhh good to know it was a mistake. Thanks for the snippet. Just used it.