# How to use JGit API to find if a file is add, modified or deleted

Tags: java, jgit

I can get an indication that a file was Added, Modified or Deleted using the **git log --pretty=format: --name-status** command.

What part of the JGit API would give me access to this status?

For example, the jGit cookbook does give an example of getting file modes:

```
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(false);
treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create("src"));
if (!treeWalk.next()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Did not find expected file 'README.md'");
}

// FileMode now indicates that this is a directory, i.e. FileMode.TREE.equals(fileMode) holds true
FileMode fileMode = treeWalk.getFileMode(0);
```

Where your can get info of the type of file from:

```
FileMode.REGULAR_FILE
```

I have looked at the API documentation at `org.eclipse.jgit.lib.AnyObjectId` etc. but am not finding an obvious path to where the API would provide information about the operation being an Add, Delete or Modification on the file in the commit.

Comment: The `FileMode` is the wrong place to look at - it just tells you whether a tree entry represents a file, a directory or a link. You can only tell if a file was added changed or removed when comparing two commits. Thus I think what you are looking for [was asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785364/jgit-list-of-files-changed-between-commits/28793479#28793479).

Comment: bingo. thanks very much for the quick response.

Comment: Glad to see your problem solved. I you don't object I will flag this question as duplicate.

Comment: I still think it deserves a direct answer from me once I have done it.

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast and already flagged the post as duplicate. But I think the moderators will read your comment and reject my suggestion.

Comment: just to confirm. the other answer implied you can only get the Add,Delete,Modified attribute from the Diff between two commits? If so this can be closed as a dupe.

Comment: Right, a commit can be seen as a snapshot of your working directory and thus changes (add, delete, modify) can only be made out when comparing commits (i.e. diff).