# JGit - Using parameters with LogCommand

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm using JGit to provide a service that will give information about various remote repositories. I'm trying to use JGit's `LogCommand` to do this, however I have been unable to find a way to do this.

I'm trying to achieve something analogous to doing the following:

```
git log --author="<username>" --pretty=tformat: --shortstat
```

However, I can't find any functionality that does that. Is there a way I could do this, with or without JGit?

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared with native Git's `log` command, the `LogCommand` if JGit offers only basic options. But there is a `RevWalk` in JGit that allows to specify custom filters while iterating over commits.

For example:

```java
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( repo );
walk.markStart( walk.parseCommit( repo.resolve( Constants.HEAD ) ) );
walk.sort( RevSort.REVERSE ); // chronological order
walk.setRevFilter( myFilter );
for( RevCommit commit : walk ) {
  // print commit
}
walk.close();
```

An example `RevFilter` that includes only commits of 'author' could look like this:

```java
RevFilter filter = new RevFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean include( RevWalk walker, RevCommit commit )
    throws StopWalkException, IOException
  {
    return commit.getAuthorIdent().getName().equals( "author" );
  }

  @Override
  public RevFilter clone() {
    return this; // may return this, or a copy if filter is not immutable
  }
};
```

To abort the walk, a filter may throws a `StopWalkException`.

Comment: looks good, but is there a way to get the lines of revisions/deletions?

Comment: How to list the changes between two commits, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361538/jgit-show-changes-between-commits) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785364/jgit-list-of-files-changed-between-commits)