# How to get the changed files list for a commit with JGit

Tags: jgit

I want to get the changed files between two commits, not the diff information, how can I use JGit to make it?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785364/list-of-files-changed-between-commits-with-jgit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of files changed between commits with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785364/list-of-files-changed-between-commits-with-jgit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two refs pointing at the two commits it should suffice to do the following to iterate all changes between the commits:

```
        ObjectId oldHead = repository.resolve("HEAD^^^^{tree}");
        ObjectId head = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");

        // prepare the two iterators to compute the diff between
        try (ObjectReader reader = repository.newObjectReader()) {
            CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
            oldTreeIter.reset(reader, oldHead);
            CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
            newTreeIter.reset(reader, head);

            // finally get the list of changed files
            try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
                List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff()
                                    .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                                    .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                                    .call();
                for (DiffEntry entry : diffs) {
                    System.out.println("Entry: " + entry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a ready-to-run example snippet contained in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowChangedFilesBetweenCommits.java)

Comment: However, DiffEntry can only provide information like newPath and oldPath. How can I use the paths or other possible information provided by DiffEntry to get the files changed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "files changed" missing. You get the new/old path as part of the DiffEntry. For non-moves it will be the same for both "old" and "new", so for simple modifications, either will be your "path"